# Using sencha touch and sencha extjs applications in one page?

Tags: extjs, frameworks, touch

I need using sencha touch and sencha extjs in one page **without conflict**?
How i can do that?

Example: First application using mobile container. But desktop application will be create container for touch application. I need solution without using iframe.

ExtJS version: ExtJS 4.1.3

Sencha Touch version: 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never mix it up**

Develop both applications independent and detect the client browser type (mobile / Desktop). Then return either a touch application or a ExtJS application. The MVC implementations are quite different between SenchaTouch and ExtJS. It will be hard to create a 'core' that can be used by both frameworks if it will be possible at all.

If you need, for what ever reason, a UI element of the other framework use either a iframe or create it yourself.

Comment: ... a little poor that this is not standardized in any way - as well as their poor support for developers who actually purchased a 4.x license but no so called "support subscription". I've just realized the scam.